# Activity double inheritance - horrible code

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-fragments, android-activity

The problem is that my activity, working activity not abstract, need to inherit some properties from other classes ,but the problem is that Java doesn't support multiple inheritance, so there only can be serial chain.

Here is my class hierarchy.

**First class** is for holding fragment (only one fragment) and toolbar, this is also bad practice to have class with multiple responsibilities (SOLID), but I have no idea how to solve this problem. It would be better to separate into SingleFragment and ToolbarActivity but this will lead to the same problem that I want to solve.

```
public abstract class SingleFragmentToolBarActivity<T extends Fragment> extends AppCompatActivity implements ScrollableToolbarFragment.ToolbarProvider {
    protected Toolbar mToolBar;
    private float mDisplayDpHeight;
    private float mDisplayDpWidth;
    protected abstract T createFragment();
    protected abstract int getFragmentContainerId();
    protected abstract int getLayoutId();
   // protected abstract int getActivityTag();
    protected abstract int getToolBarId();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayoutId());
        mToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(getToolBarId());
        mToolBar = setUpToolbar(mToolBar);
        // TODO Fix style or theme !! Just temporary solution
        mToolBar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        int fragmentContainerId = getFragmentContainerId();
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(fragmentContainerId);
        if (fragment==null) {
            fragment = createFragment();
            fragmentTransaction
                    .add(fragmentContainerId,fragment)
                    .commit();
        }

    }
```

This is not full class declaration, only most important part.(Setting content layout)

This class looks quite normally, if not take into account the multiple responsibility.

**Second class** is responsible for implementing NavigationDrawer, in my case I am using [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/) library here. This is great library, author has used **InversionOfControl** to add navigation drawer to any activity in runtime. But this doesn't help in my case.

```
public abstract class NavigationDrawerActivity<T extends Fragment> extends SingleFragmentToolBarActivity<T> {
    private float mDisplayDpWidth;
    private float mDisplayDpHeight;
    private Drawer.Result mNavigationDrawer;
    private AccountHeader.Result mAccountHeader;
    private double mDrawerWidthFactor = 0.9;
    private double mDrawerHeaderHeightFactor = 0.3;
    private IProfile<ProfileDrawerItem> mProfile;
    ProfileSettingDrawerItem settingDrawerItem;
    public Drawer.Result getNavigationDrawer() {
        return this.mNavigationDrawer;
    }
    private AccountHeader.Result geAccountHeader() {
        return this.mAccountHeader;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setUpNavigationDrawer(savedInstanceState);
    }
private void setUpNavigationDrawer(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDisplayMetrics();
        mAccountHeader = new AccountHeader()
                .withActivity(this)
       //.....
        Drawer buildDrawer =  new Drawer(this)
                .withActivity(this);
        .......



    }
```

For me personally it looks horrible, this class is derived from **SingleFragmentToolBarActivity**. And when I have to inherit from  `NavigationDrawerActivity` I need to declare my class like this

```
public class TestActivity extends NavigationDrawerActivity<ScrollableTestFragment> {
```

I know what does this line of code mean.But if another developer will look at this code he will be confused, why does he need to generalize `NavigationDrawerActivity` with Fragment class ?

I have tried to apply several patterns here, but nothing really works as it should.

Decorator - decorating activity can be quite difficult to wrap all activity methods, as far as Activity is kind of God Object. And delegating all methods to the internally stored (as class member) wrapped activity can be painful and not good choice at all.

Strategy - use interfaces as class members will not help because all these features (single framgent, navigtation drawer...) tightly coupled to the Activity base class and to my mind it cannot suit well in this situation.

Comment: if you make the base class interface would solve your problem..

Comment: Base class, you mean to put all this functionality into one class, of course it will work ,but this break SOLID principle.

Comment: No, I din't say that. Actually I said that if you made the NavigationDrawerActivity interface, then you would keep the inheritance and polymorphism that provides java.

Comment: How can I achieve   Drawer buildDrawer =  new Drawer(this) using interface ? Use something like setupNavigationDrawer(Activitiy activity) ?

Comment: What you can do is to use composition instead of inheritance - create some “manager” classes that you would be able to use in your activities.